# Apply conditional formatting to large number of text cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a table that contains up to about 100 different text values and I want to color them according to the text so that you can visually see what cells have the same text (table!B2:DB100).

I have a separate sheet that lists the values that are in the table (dynamically) (list!A1:A100).

A possible solution would be to apply a conditional formatting that figures out whether a cell in table!B2:DB100 is equal to list!A1. If so color it with color 1. Then add another conditional formatting saying if a cell in table!B2:DB100 is equal to list!A2 then color is with color 2. And so on.

Doing this manually would be painful because there are 100 possible text values.

I believe I could do it with a macro which has the added advantage that you can apply RGB values in a nice orderly way.

> Is a macro, in fact, the best way to do it? Will it bog down the spreadsheet to have ~100 conditional formattings applied? Is there a simpler way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have something working reasonably well. I wrote a macro to apply the conditional formatting.

```
Sub conditional()
'
' conditional Macro

i = 1
station = 1
colorscheme = 1
Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i + 3, 3) = ""
    a = "=Data!" + Sheets("Data").Cells(i + 3, 3).Address
    c1 = 255
    c2 = 147 + 17 * station
    Select Case colorscheme
        Case 1 'red
            mycolor = RGB(c1, c2, c2)
        Case 2 'yellow
            mycolor = RGB(c1, c1, c2)
        Case 3 'green
            mycolor = RGB(c2, c1, c2)
        Case 4 'cyan
            mycolor = RGB(c2, c1, c1)
        Case 5 'blue
            mycolor = RGB(c2, c2, c1)
        Case 6 'purple
            mycolor = RGB(c1, c2, c1)
    End Select
    Range("H4:BE48").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=a, _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    With Range("H4:BE48").FormatConditions(Range("H4:BE48").FormatConditions.Count)
        .Interior.Color = mycolor
        .StopIfTrue = True
    End With
    i = i + 1
    station = station + 1
    If station = 5 Then
        station = 1
        colorscheme = colorscheme + 1
    End If
    If colorscheme = 7 Then
        colorscheme = 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

And here's how it looks in an example:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

I'd welcome any comments, suggestions, or improvements.